# Python recursion (maybe recursion within recursion?) to divide e.g. string into substrings (each of which could have more substrings)

Tags: python, recursion

I have very little experience with recursive functions, but now I have a problem that I think could be solved much easier recursively. I would also like to take this opportunity to finally learn more about recursive functions in general.

**Problem:**
I have some input string that can be subdivided into e.g. 3 parts (but let´s assume I don´t know in advance how many parts) and each of those parts can be further subdivided into sub_parts etc.

**Example:**
full_string = "[Part1: [many sub_parts of Part1]] and [Part2: [many sub_parts of Part2]] and [Part3: [many sub_parts of Part3]]"

After calling the function recursive_func(full_string) the full_string will be subdivided into:

1. Result of first run:  [Part1: [many sub_parts of Part1]]
2. Result of second run: [Part2: [many sub_parts of Part2]]
3. Result of third run:  [Part3: [many sub_parts of Part3]]

Here my function stops. But what i would like it to do is now do the same with the sub_parts. Each sub_part could then exist of even more sub_parts etc.

So the required output would look something like this:

**Input:** full_string = [Part1: "[sub_parts of Part1]] and [Part2: [sub_parts of Part2]] and [Part3: [sub_parts of Part3]]"

```
recursive_func(full_string)
```

**Output:**

Output:

```
Part1
    sub_part1
        sub_sub_part1
        sub_sub_part2
        sub_sub_partx
    sub_partX
        sub_sub_part1
        sub_sub_part2
            ...
        sub_sub_partx
            ...
                ...
                    ...
Part2
    sub_part1
        sub_sub_part1
        sub_sub_part2
        sub_sub_partx
PartX
    sub_part1
        sub_sub_part1
        sub_sub_part2
        sub_sub_partx
            sub_sub_sub_partx
                ...
```

So basically I only get the first level of the output (Part1, Part2, Part3) and I don´t know what is a reasonable way to set up this recursion to include all of the sub_parts (and their sub_sub_parts etc.).

Here is my function. I replaced most of it with pseudocode so that it is somewhat clear what i want to do.

```
def recursive_func(s, result=None, i = 0):

    print(i)

    if result is None:
        result = []

    if THERE IS AT LEAST ONE PART LEFT TO BE EXTRACTED IN THE STRING:

        EXTRACT ONE PART CALLED f_str

        # Append this part to the result
        result.append(f_str)

        # remove the part from the string
        s = s.replace(f_str,"", 1)

        return drill_down(s, result, i+1)
    
    # I am thinking that maybe here i would need to start another recursion?
    return result
```

Comment: " I replaced most of it with pseudocode" - well, then there's no way for us to run it. Please consider providing a [mre]

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I will try to reduce the code as good as I can and add it above.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i cannot simplify the quite complex string extraction. If no answers are possible based on the pseudocode i would appreciate it if this question could be closed. Thanks!